# Compiling and Installing Yate from SVN on Debian

Tags: linux, svn, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install Yate from SVN on my Raspberry Pi through the command line via this tutorial:
http://docs.yate.ro/wiki/Compiling_and_Installing_Yate_from_SVN_on_Debian

When I get to this step:

cd /usr/src
   svn checkout http://voip.null.ro/svn/yate/trunk yate

I get an error saying "svn: E000013: Can't make directory '/usr/src/yate': Permission denied"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to fix this, is to run it as root. this seems ok, as the later steps seem to require root privileges as well. in general it might be possible to run the commands as a normal user in another directory.

Comment: I am running root.  Only 1 user "pi"